# Send an email message via script upon startup, before user login

Tags: macos, email, startup, automation

Is there any way to automatically send an email message (as a notification that my server box has rebooted, usually due to power failure) to myself upon system startup, before user login?

I am not very familiar with scripting but am willing to try my best.

I am guessing that /Library/LaunchDaemons is the place to call the script?

Comment: why before user log in ?

Comment: @Buscar웃:  because the server is password protected and requires a user to log in. I want to be notified if the server suffers a power failure, which will cause it to reboot automatically, but be left at the user login screen.